# What is the best way to upgrade Abp Framework 4.1.0 to latest version 6.3.1?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

What is the best way to upgrade Abp Framework 4.1.0 to latest version 6.3.1? And does it upgrades EF core version and .Net core version?

Comment: When I want to update I just download the lasted version from aspnetboilerplate's page and then I move all my project files to this new project, I some hours I have all updated.

Answer (score 1):

Steps

1. Update the .net framework to the latest version
2. You can update the nuget packages related to abp to the latest version
3. Add a migration (update the database), this because there are changes in the properties of the framework entities

The UI theme was also changed to AdminLte, although this should not be a problem.
Lucky!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7903861/washyn-acero